# How to remove dot and slash from the beginning of a string in bash?

Tags: bash

I want to remove `./` from the beginning of `./Accounts`.

Here's my script:

```
export Item=./Accounts
echo $Item
export ReplacedItem=${$Item/.\//}
echo $ReplacedItem
```

But I get:

> main.sh: line 3: ReplacedItem=${$Item/.//}: bad substitution

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Use the standard `sh` `${param#pattern}` operator¹, no need for the `${param/pattern/replacement}` (not <strike>`${$param/pattern/replacement}`</strike>) ksh93-style one here.

Also, there's no point exporting those variables unless you want other commands to inherit them. Also remember `echo` can't be used to print arbitrary data, and parameter expansions must be quoted² in `bash`.

```
Item=./Accounts
printf '%s\n' "$Item"
ReplacedItem="${Item#./}"
printf '%s\n' "$Item"
```

If using ksh93-style `${param/pattern/replacement}`, that should be:

```
ReplacedItem="${Item/.\//}"
```

Though you can omit the `/` before the pattern and replacement if the replacement is an empty string:

```
ReplacedItem="${Item/.\/}"
```

But beware it remove the first occurrence of `./` in `$Item`, even if it's not at the start. To remove it only if it's at the start, you can add `#` at the start of the pattern.

```
ReplacedItem="${Item/#.\/}"
```

(but again, no advantage over the standard `${Item#./}`).

---

<sup>¹ originally from ksh, already there in ksh85, and specified by POSIX for `sh` in the early nineties so supported by all standard `sh` implementations including `bash` the GNU implementation of `sh`.</sup>

<sup>² At least those in list contexts. Quotes are not strictly necessary in `var=$param` (assignment to a *scalar* variable, not a *list* / *array* variable) and some other non-list contexts, but don't harm.</sup>